# Division ring which is algebraic over $\mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am looking for the proof of the following

> Theorem. If $L$ is a division ring algebraic over $\mathbb R$, then $L$ is $\mathbb R$-isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb H$ , where $\mathbb H$ is a field of quaternions and $\mathbb C$ as usual the field of complex numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29 $\:$

Answer (score 1):

One proof is in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Comment: any precise page number , if u know ?

Comment: @Theorem : pages 173, 222, 428.